# MySQL CONCAT cannot concat more than 2 items

Tags: sql

I am currently studying SQL and am completing Hackerrank Questions ([this is the question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-pads/problem?isFullScreen=true)). The question involves concatenating strings. However when I use CONCAT according to convention, i.e:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(NAME, '(', LEFT(Occupation,1), ')')
FROM 
    OCCUPATIONS;
```

I receive the following error:

```
> SQL0440N No authorized routine named "CONCAT" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found. SQLSTATE=42884
```

However, if I enter the following code:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(NAME, CONCAT(CONCAT('(', LEFT(Occupation,1)), ')'))
FROM 
    OCCUPATIONS;
```

The code runs correctly and I receive the following output:

```
Kristeen(S) 
Maria(P) 
Meera(P) 
Naomi(P) 
Priya(D)
```

I have tried to use escape characters to no avail. I am able to concatenate any of the two strings fine however when I attempt to join any more than that in the cone CONCAT function I am unable.

Is this an error with my code, or an error with the platform? I have reviewed other solutions online that is coded exactly like the first solution and they are able to submit.

Comment: Use the ANSI/ISO SQL standard `||` concatenation instead. E.g. `'abc' || 'def' || 'g'` will give you `'abcdefg'`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that on Hackerrank I had not changed the language from DB2 to MySQL in the top right hand corner, the error I was receiving was because I was using MySQL syntax where it wasn't supported.